# php7 psr-4 composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I'm trying to create a new project with autoload psr4. When i run the test, i get error. Can not found the class. How can i solve that?

Edit: I added phpunit.xml. I'm using phpunit 6.5.

Error: Class 'FizzBuzz\FizzBuzz' not found

/Sites/fizzbuzz/tests/FizzBuzzTest.php:15

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "FizzBuzz\\": "src/"
    }
}
}
```

FizzBuzzTest.php

```
<?php

use FizzBuzz\FizzBuzz;

class FizzBuzzTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function test_example(){
        $parser = new FizzBuzz();
        $this->assertEquals(0, $parser->parse());
    }
}
```

FizzBuzz.php

```
<?php

namespace FizzBuzz;

class FizzBuzz
{
    public function parse(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
     verbose="true">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="small">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Framework</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Runner</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Util</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="large">
        <directory suffix=".phpt">tests/TextUI</directory>
        <directory suffix=".phpt">tests/Regression</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php</file>
            <file>src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>

<php>
    <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" value="true"/>
</php>
```

Comment: If you're running on Windows, it could be that you need to rename your directory to FizzBuzz, since Windows is case-sensitive.

Comment: I'm running on Mac. @qvotaxon

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` after adding the `psr-4` entry?

Comment: @Marwelln Yes, I did.

Comment: Where is `FizzBuzz.php` placed relative to `composer.json`?

Comment: Reading the [psr-4 specification](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#2-specification) it seems to me that the specification itself forces case-sensitivity. Could you try renaming your directory so that the cases are the same? Could you please add your directory structure as it is right now to the post?

Comment: @Marwelln You can check my folder design https://imgur.com/a/ycEw8

Comment: @qvotaxon I changed but does not work.

Comment: Did you maybe forgot to include vendor/autoload.php?

Comment: @René Where should i include it?

Comment: First off, yes, with psr-4 the directory names must match the case of the namespace you are using, as @qvotaxon stated.  For phpunit do you have a phpunit.xml?  Is that pointing to your autoloader?

Comment: @gview Yes, phpunit works right.

Comment: It doesn't work right if it doesn't autoload the classes you are trying to test.   Update your question with your phpunit.xml

Comment: @gview Edited question.

Comment: But i just use the command while i run phpunit. `./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/FizzBuzzTest`

Comment: What is in tests/bootstrap.php?

Comment: There is nothing something like bootstrap.php. @gview

Comment: Your phpunit.xml is configured to load that:  bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164015/discussion-between-onur-and-gview).